# dagster: how do I get modified assets only? (external api)

Tags: python, dagster

I'm learning dagster so maybe I haven't fully grasped the concepts.

my goal is to query an external web services / api and get the modified records only. I can make the external call a resource or put it into the asset directly, right? The external resource has filter option for last modified.

For me the core question is where and how to I pass in the value (in this case a date)? All records changed after this date (eg. the last run) should be fetched from the external api?

So were do I store this date and how do I pass it to the asset?

Answer (score 0):

If you're modeling your code as a sensor then you'll want to check out [sensor cursors](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/partitions-schedules-sensors/sensors#sensor-optimizations-using-cursors). This is where you'd store the date between sensor evaluations.

Otherwise if all your logic is just inside Dagster ops / assets, I think you'll need to just store that state on your own - in DynamoDB or S3 or whatever your preferred external state store is. Dagster doesn't really have first-class support for this kind of external state.